# Bumblebee applications running very slow

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

My laptop has NVIDIA GT 520MX discrete graphics. I installed Bumblebee to take advantage of OPTIMUS technology. But applications are running slow with Bumblebee. Applications with small memory footprint like Mines game and gedit are running fine(ran them with Bumblebee just for testing). But video playback with Totem is very laggy. Frame rate is too low. Firefox is also comparatively slow. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah. Linux driver support sucks. This is why Linux will never be a Desktop platform for people who value their own personal time. Hardware / chip manufacturers don't write quality drivers for their hardware targeting Linux, so Linux users are out of luck. The only option is to buy hardware that is qualified by Canoncial / Ubuntu / etc to run on certain releases. But this leaves out a lot of the hardware we want to use.